# Why is somthing like ++(++(*++b)) illegal?

Tags: c, increment

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[3] = {1, 2, 3};
    int *b = a;
    int c = ++(++(*++b)); /* error: lvalue required as increment operand */
    printf("%d", c);

    return 0;
}
```

But the following is legal:

```
int c = *++b+1+1;
```

Why such a difference exists?

Comment: @KamiKaze This is rather about `++b` not being a lvalue.

Comment: The result of the `++` operators is not a so-called _lvalue_. That is, the result is a value but not one you can modify. The result of the `*` operator is however always a lvalue. This is why `++*++b` is syntactically correct but `++++*++b` is not.

Comment: Even if it had been legal, why would you like to write a longer and more complicated code, when there is a shorter (and legal) version? I also recommend `+ 2` over `+1+1`.

Comment: @Bo In practical use, I will surely not do that; now I just want to understand the language, so I asked the question.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

The following one `int c = *++b+1+1;` is legal because of

- there are 3 operator namely `*`, `++` and `+` and check `man 1 operator` `*` and `++` having same precedence so check associativity which is `R-->L`
- so 1st `*++b` is solved which is valid & it gives value `2`
- Now it  looks like `int c = 2+1+1` which is also valid `C` statement

And `int c = ++(++(*++b));` is illegal because first `*++b` is performed which gives one value lets say `2(res)` now you are doing `++res` which results in an integer value `3` until this is fine, next when you do `++3` which is invalid because `++` is applicable on variable not on constants. So it gives **lvalue** error.

Comment: tell the reason of downvote, I'll delete it.

Comment: Not the downvoter, but a more precise explanation would involve rvalues and lvalues.